# natural embedding of normed linear space is an isometry

Tags: functional-analysis

To review for an exam, I'm trying to write up a short proof of the following:

> Let $J: X \rightarrow X^{**}$ be the natural embedding of the normed
>   linear space $X$ into its bidual $X^{**}$, given by $J(x) = f(x)$. This embedding is a linear and isometric.

The Hahn-Banach theorem gives us $\phi \in X^*$ (a linear functional on $X$) which $\| \phi \| =1$ and $f(x) =  \|x\|$. This implies $||x|| \leq \|J(x)\|$.

I have difficulty in following the proofs demonstrating that the embedding is bounded, that $\|J(x)\| \leq \|x\|.$ How can this be proven in a short manner without being "handwaving in manner"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $ \mathbb{S}(X^{*}) $ denote the unit sphere in $ X^{*} $. Then
\begin{align}
\| J(x) \|_{X^{**}}
&\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \sup_{\varphi \in \mathbb{S}(X^{*})} |[J(x)](\varphi)| \\
&=                        \sup_{\varphi \in \mathbb{S}(X^{*})} |\varphi(x)| \\
&\leq                     \sup_{\varphi \in \mathbb{S}(X^{*})} \| \varphi \|_{X^{*}}
                          \cdot \| x \|_{X} \\
&=                        \| x \|_{X}. \quad
(\text{As $ \| \varphi \|_{X^{*}} = 1 $ for all $ \varphi \in \mathbb{S}(X^{*}) $.})
\end{align}

Comment: It didn't seem that simple from our book. Thanks.

Comment: You’re welcome! :) Actually, proving the other direction should be harder than the one that I proved here, because it is not very obvious that one has to use the Hahn-Banach Theorem.