# prove that a sequence is bounded in the bidual

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

let E be a normed vector space , let $x_{n}$ be a bounded sequence on E , prove that  $x_{n}$ is bounded on the bidual E**.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: "bounded sequence *on*" or *in*?

Comment: Duplicate: [natural embedding of normed linear space is an isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314689/natural-embedding-of-normed-linear-space-is-an-isometry)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let $\{x_n\}\subset E$ be a bounded sequence, i.e. $\|x_n\|\le M$, for some $M>0$.

Then set $\varphi_n \in E^{**}$, defined as
$$
\varphi_n(x^*)=x^*(x_n), \quad x^*\in E^*.
$$
Then, for $\|x^*\|_*=1$ we have
$$
|\varphi_n(x^*)|=|x^*(x_n)|\le \|x^*\|_*\|x_n\|=\|x_n\|\le M.
$$
Then $\|\varphi_n\|\le M$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: We are not supposed to answer such no-effort questions. Moreover, it is a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Smyrlis for your answer.